# Security mechanism in WSDL

Tags: web-services, security, wsdl

I want to know how WSDL secure data on trafic. I searched but I can't find anything I need. This is a WSDL service sample and I want to understand their security mechanism.

```
<wsdl:definitions 
    xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"   
    xmlns:impl="http://services.test" xmlns:intf="http://services.test" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://services.test">
    <!--
       WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
       Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)
     -->
    ....
    <wsdl:types>....
    <wsdl:message....
    <wsdl:portType>
        <wsdl:operation ....
    <wsdl:binding name="InterfacesSoapBinding" type="impl:Interfaces">
        <wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="topup">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="topupRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://services.test" use="encoded"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="topupResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://services.test" use="encoded"/>
            </wsdl:output>
         </wsdl:operation>
     </wsdl:binding>
     ....
     <wsdl:service name="InterfacesService">
         <wsdl:port binding="impl:InterfacesSoapBinding" name="Interfaces">
             <wsdlsoap:address location="...."/>
         </wsdl:port>
     </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

This

```
<wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://services.test" use="encoded"/>
```

is encode data trafic right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example there is no security declaration at all. The `encodingStyle` defines only how your SOAP message is encoded and serialized. And the declared encoding style `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding` is the standard one. See [SOAP encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383512) for more details.

If you want to learn something about securing a WSDL/SOAP web service please check the OASIS website e.g. [WS-SecurityPolicy Examples](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/security-policy/examples/ws-sp-usecases-examples.html#wss11) or especially for message encryption [SOAP Message security](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/v1.1/wss-v1.1-spec-errata-os-SOAPMessageSecurity.pdf). In general there are several security approaches for WSDL/SOAP for different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

`WS-Policy` declaration is the way to provide security for `SOAP` web services. You need to implement the `wsp:PolicyReference` in your `WSDL` file. A complete tutorial is here(https://concentricsky.com/blog/article/implementing-ws-security-cxf-wsdl-first-web-service).